# Accommodating larger screens with responsive design

Tags: html, css

A webpage I designed when viewed on a much larger screen (27 inches), has a lot of empty white space it doesn't fill. How would I handle this issue? I've used media queries to be accommodating to resolutions that are most common already. How should I design for much larger screens? Should I have a fluid layout as well for a more future proof solution and to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make the layout flexible, or build a new responsive layout for larger displays set with @media queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use a min-width media query to target larger screens.

```
/* Target 1200px wide and above */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

That would change the font color on the body if the screen was wider than 1200px, it wont apply to screens 1199px and below.

Answer (score 0):

Add a background texture to a wrapping div to fill in the space or if you like, add in a background that can be even 3000px + wide and just simply center it so that it will continue outward if the screen gets larger but will still be fine for smaller resolutions.

Typically you could also have a responsive layout that works off @media queries etc.

Here are a few examples of this:

- http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/resolution/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/
- http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/